# examples of DCI architecture?

Tags: architecture, dci

I've been trying to understand [DCI](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/05/dci-coplien-reenskau) architecture by reading [lean software architecture](http://www.leansoftwarearchitecture.com/). I feel like I need to see some more examples to crystalize my understanding of it, but I've only been able to find ones which are variations of the [money transfer between accounts](http://horsdal.blogspot.com/2009/05/dci-in-c.html) case that is worked through in the book.

If there are any out there on the web, let me know. Alternatively if you've created an good example yourself that isn't on the web, you could post it here.

Any language will do.

Comment: There is a very good sample for it at https://github.com/vsavkin/DCI-Sample

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure, if you had look at some of these literature on the web.
I am listing them down for reference:

- http://folk.uio.no/trygver/2008/commonsense.pdf
- http://www.artima.com/articles/dci_vision.html
- http://pettermahlen.com/2010/09/10/dci-architecture-good-not-great-or-both/
- http://groups.google.com/group/object-composition/
- http://www.jroller.com/sebastianKuebeck/entry/james_coplien_s_talk_on
- http://www.infoq.com/presentations/The-DCI-Architecture

And the following discusses the application using an example in scala

- http://sadekdrobi.com/2009/06/10/dci-in-real-world-domain-context-and-interaction-with-scala-in-a-real-world-project/#more-638

Comment: I found Petter Mahlen's follow up post: "DCI better with DI" to be really useful too

Comment: @JonnyCundall do however keep in mind that that article has a few misrepresentations of what DCI is

Answer (score 4):

DCI has it's own web site at [fullOO.info](http://fulloo.info) it's not completed yet but does have links to publications and literature in general as well as a number of examples in different languages either written by one of the co-founders of DCI or reviewed and accepted by one of them.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented an experimental network protocol analyzer (in C++) 
based on the DCI.

You can get more details from

http://dimitri-christodoulou.blogspot.com/search/label/DCI

and source code here:

https://github.com/dimitrs/DCI-NIDS

Answer (score 2):

The Qi4j Java framework comes with samples, one of each, DCI-Cargo, is an implementation of the cargo application from the DDD book using DCI.

Here is a link to the sample : http://qi4j.org/_dci_cargo_sample.html

And some literature about it by its author Marc Grue : http://marcgrue.com/

The sample is thoroughly unit tested, implement persistence etc...

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Did an injectionless type macro [implementation of DCI in Scala](https://github.com/DCI/scaladci) and posted some [examples](https://github.com/DCI/scaladci/tree/master/examples/src/test/scala/scaladci/examples) at Github that you can check out...

Answer (score 1):

I've just released a DCI library in C# with generously commented examples. Check it out, any comments are welcome:

https://github.com/ciscoheat/ivento-dci